# Define Custom Callback Function Bokeh TapTool

Tags: python, bokeh

I have a BarPlot (Not `Chart` but built from `figure`) that I am embedding in a Flask app. I want to execute some function every time a bar is clicked upon (via TapTool). May I know how do I do that ?

One way I see is to use TapTool's callback function like the one shown in [docs](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction.html#openurl). But how do I use a custom defined function (Not CustomJs but a normal Python func) instead of say OpenUrl Callback Function ? Also how can I access that `@foo` kind-of variables in a user defined function ?

Thanks.

```
Python 3.5, Bokeh 0.11
```

[image: Bar Plot]

Comment: In the code of CustomJs you can call `jQuery.ajax()` to generate a request to Flask server.